# Fetching number of unread messages from MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am developing an Android chat application.
I have two tables.

```
Table: chats

id  sender_id receiver_id message  read_status  sender_name

1    22         11        hi..      1          raaj
2    22         11        hey.      1          raaj
3    22         11        nice.     0          raaj
4    22         11        wow       0          raaj
5    22         11        thanx     0          raaj
6    11         22        yup       0          deep
7    33         11        hi..      1          sanju
```

```
Table read:

id   status
0     unread
1     read
```

```
About users
id--> 22 -->raaj

id-->11--->deep

id--->33--->sanju
```

I have to get `DISTINCT sender_id , sender_name , no. of unread messages WHERE sender_id != '11'`

I need result something like this:

```
sender_id   sender_name  no_of_unread_messages
22          raaj            3
33          sanju           0
```

How can I do this in MySQL using one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sender_id, sender_name, COUNT(*) no_of_unread_messages
FROM chats
WHERE sender_id != 11
  AND read_status=0
GROUP BY sender_id
```

if you need records with SUM = 0 try this one:

```
SELECT sender_id, sender_name, SUM(IF(read_status=0,1,0)) no_of_unread_messages
FROM chats
WHERE sender_id != 11
GROUP BY sender_id
```

Comment: yes, and imho sender_name shouldn't be a part of chats table. it must be in users table only

Comment: @xQbert . sender_name is a part of user table . sorry i could not mention here. Thanks

Comment: @Alex . your query gave me result like this                                      sender_id   sender_name  no_of_unread_messages
22                   raaj                  3

Comment: @Alex . I need likesender_id                                                    sender_name     no_of_unread_messages
22           raaj            3
33           sanju           0

Comment: @Alex Query is not showing the raw which does not have no of unread messages. how should do this ?

Comment: @Alex . Can you plz tell me how can i apply same query in SQLite Database as i have to implement the same at android side as well . I tried this query in SQLite , but it shows error  "No such function : IF  "

Comment: @Alex  Can you plz tell me how can achieve the same result with out using GROUP BY clause . I tried you query at android programming .                         At android  I am using an Interface LoaderManager which is the fastest way to acccess database , and  has other good features , but the problem is that , it does not support GROUP BY clause . So Plz tell me how can i find the same result but without using GROUP BY clause . Thank you

Comment: @xQbert . Edited part of answer is solution of my problem using MYSQL database , but i have to get same result in android using SQLITE database . At android I am using an Interface LoaderManager which is the fastest way to acccess database , and has other good features , but the problem is that , it does not support GROUP BY clause . So Plz tell me how can i find the same result but without using GROUP BY clause . Thank you

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) and [SQLLite](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) extends the group by clause so you don't HAVE to have one but then each non aggregate field MUST be identical in values or the engine randomly selects a value to populate the the non-aggregate values.   So simply removing the group by will work, but you could get unexpected results if column values vary for the non-aggregates.